# Move text up a line in Unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file containing a suite of jobs that look like the below job. What I would like to do is move the `JOB_NAME` onto the `delete_job:` line for each job to look like

```
delete_job: JOB_NAME
```

I have tried many ways but can't get it to work! Any ideas how this can be achieved?

```
delete_job:
JOB_NAME
job_type: BOX
description: "*******"
date_conditions: 0
owner: *******
alarm_if_fail: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** As per ED sir's suggestion adding 1 more solution too now.

```
awk 'val{print val OFS $0;val="";next}/delete_job/||/update_job/||/insert_job/{val=$0;next} 1' Input_file
```

---

***EDIT:*** as OP told many strings could be there to search so changing accordingly now.

```
awk '/delete_job/||/update_job/||/insert_job/{val=$0;getline;print val OFS $0;next} 1' Input_file
```

---

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/delete_job/{val=$0;getline;print val OFS $0;next} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: Don't do this, it's the wrong approach as it can fail silently and cryptically and is hard to enhance later if/when your requirements change.See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. As a trivial example of difficulty enhancing - try adding a statement to print every input line to stderr (e.g. for debugging) and notice that if you have a getline solution you need to add the print in 2 separate locations where as with a non-getline solution you can just add a print at the front of the script.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks sir, could you please check my latest EDIT solution and provide your guidance if that looks good now?

Comment: The first script no longer has the getline problems, it's now just a bit lengthier and more complicated than it has to be, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51046879/1745001). I'm removing my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

With good old ed:

```
ed infile <<'EOE'
g/^delete_job:$/ s/$/ /\
.,+j
wq
EOE
```

This collects all lines that match `^delete_job:$` with the `g//` global command; `s/$/ /` appends a space to that line, and `.,+j` joins it with the next line before `wq` writes the buffer back to the file and exits.

Answer (score 1):

A sed solution:

```
sed '/^delete_job:$/{N;s/\n/ /;}' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this with awk (assuming multiple possible "action_job" lines) is to just save the "action_job" line when you see it and then print it as a prefix when you're printing the next line:

```
awk '/(delete|update|insert)_job/{act=$0 OFS; next} {print act $0; act=""}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use awk, perhaps something like

```
<yourfile awk '
BEGIN { output = 1 }
/delete_job:/ { output = 0; next; }
output == 0 { print "delete_job: " $0; output = 1; next; }
output == 1 { print }' > newfile
```

Maybe that helps. The result will be written to newfile.

Answer (score 0):

two other `awk`s

```
$ awk '/^delete_job:/{printf "%s", $0 OFS; next}1' file
```

or

```
$ awk '{ORS=/^delete_job:/?OFS:RS}1' file
```

Comment: Hi mate, that first one worked a treat, thanks a lot! Is it possible to wildcard the delete_job: as it can sometimes vary between, delete/update/insert? Thanks again

Comment: @CameronCharlton, please check my EDIT solution once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @CameronCharlton That should be part of the initial question then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yeah that worked! Thanks buddy, we couldn't figure it out all day and this has been up less than 30 mins, I'm just coming straight here next time... Cheers.

Comment: @CameronCharlton, not an issue, buddy happy learning and keep learning, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

With `paste`, `head` and `tail`:

```
$ (head -n2 | paste -d' ' -s; tail -n+1) < filename.txt
```